# FlashChat installation hiccup! SQL syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I've done away with the (14) and (11) but when trying to install tufat's Flashchat, I keep getting this error:

> Could not create DB table 'smf_fc_bans'You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL, userid int(11)
>   default NULL, banneduserid int(11) default NULL, r' at line 1

Granted I'm still such a novice. If someone could help me I would be so very very grateful.

Table structure for table `bans`:

```
CREATE TABLE `bans` (
       `id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `userid` int default NULL,
       `banneduserid` int default NULL,
       `roomid` int default NULL,
       `ip` varchar default NULL,
       KEY `id` (`id`),
       KEY `userid` (`userid`),
       KEY `created` (`created`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Table structure for table `connections`:

```
CREATE TABLE `connections` (
       `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
       `updated` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `userid` int default NULL,
       `roomid` int default NULL,
       `state` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
       `color` int default NULL,
       `start` int default NULL,
       `lang` char(2) default NULL,
       `ip` varchar(16) default NULL,
       `tzoffset` int default '0',
       `chatid` int NOT NULL default '1',
       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `userid` (`userid`),
       KEY `roomid` (`roomid`),
       KEY `updated` (`updated`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Table structure for table `ignors`:

```
CREATE TABLE `ignors` (
       `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `userid` int default NULL,
       `ignoreduserid` int default NULL,
       KEY `userid` (`userid`),
       KEY `ignoreduserid` (`ignoreduserid`),
       KEY `created` (`created`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Table structure for table `messages`:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
       `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `toconnid` varchar(32) default NULL,
       `touserid` int(11) default NULL,
       `toroomid` int(11) default NULL,
       `command` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       `userid` int default NULL,
       `roomid` int(11) default NULL,
       `txt` text,
       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `touserid` (`touserid`),
       KEY `toroomid` (`toroomid`),
       KEY `toconnid` (`toconnid`),
       KEY `created` (`created`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

Table structure for table `rooms`:

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
       `id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `updated` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
       `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
       `ispublic` char(1) default NULL,
       `ispermanent` int(11) default NULL,

       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `name` (`name`),
       KEY `ispublic` (`ispublic`),
       KEY `ispermanent` (`ispermanent`),
       KEY `updated` (`updated`)
     ) WNGINW=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Table structure for table `users`:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
       `id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `login` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
       `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
       `roles` int NOT NULL default '0',
       `profile` text,
       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `login` (`login`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;`
```

Comment: No create table smf_fc_bans statement?

Comment: Not that I could find, no :(

Comment: According to RiggsFolly's answer, `bans` is the problem table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `varchar` datatype requires a parameter like `varchar(50)`

```
CREATE TABLE `bans` (
       `id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `userid` int default NULL,
       `banneduserid` int default NULL,
       `roomid` int default NULL,
       `ip` varchar( requires a number ) default NULL,    <-- HERE
       KEY `id` (`id`),
       KEY `userid` (`userid`),
       KEY `created` (`created`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

You also have an error in

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
       `id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `updated` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
       `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
       `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
       `ispublic` char(1) default NULL,
       `ispermanent` int(11) default NULL,

       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `name` (`name`),
       KEY `ispublic` (`ispublic`),
       KEY `ispermanent` (`ispermanent`),
       KEY `updated` (`updated`)
     ) WNGINW=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

WNGINW=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Should be

```
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: Hi there. Turned WNGINW to ENGINE and added a parameter where it was missing, but still no joy :( Also, thank you for your help!

Comment: Then you cannot of saved the change when you edited the file. I assume these instructions are in a file

Comment: D'oh. You were right. I hadn't saved them. It works great now. Thank you thank you for your help!